# Creating a fast Android dictionary (word counts)

Tags: java, performance, android, hash-map, sqlite

This is a follow-up of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394873/creating-a-fast-android-dictionary-word-counts#):

I am currently working on an application for various statistics. One task is to analyse a good amount of sentences for their word counts.

The specifications are:

- sentences are read from SQLiteDatabase (up to 20k with an average of about 15 words)
- transformation: split by whitespaces (to get the words of the sentences)
- transformation: toLowerCase (to minimize variations of words)
- transformation: replace [^a-zA-Z] (for the same reason as above)
- get word + count for the first x (not sure yet, maybe 10-15) most common words
- preserve a flag if the messages was sent/received

What I'm looking for:

- improvements to make the code run faster
- alternative approaches for this task
- (general hints to improve the task)

**Current version with the suggested improvements made**

```
//fields

private static final CharMatcher pat_rep = CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z').or(CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z'))
        .precomputed();
private static final Pattern pat_split = Pattern.compile("\\s");
private HashMultiset<String> sent = HashMultiset.create();
private HashMultiset<String> rcvd = HashMultiset.create();
private Cursor c1;
private Cursor c2;

//start

    c1 = db.rawQuery("select lower(DATA) as SENTENCE, SENT from MESSAGELIST", null);
    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        String[] words = pat_split.split(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("SENTENCE")));
        int from_me = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("key_from_me"));
        for (String in : words) {
            in = pat_rep.retainFrom(in);
            if (!in.equals("")) {
                if (from_me == 1) {
                    sent.add(in);
                } else {
                    rcvd.add(in);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    db.execSQL("create temp table if not exists WORDS (WORD varchar, SENT integer, CNT integer)");
    SQLiteStatement ins = db.compileStatement("insert into WORDS values (?, ?, ?)");
    db.beginTransaction();

    Iterator<Entry<String>> i = sent.entrySet().iterator();
    Entry<String> e = null;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        e = i.next();
        ins.bindString(1, e.getElement());
        ins.bindLong(2, 1);
        ins.bindLong(3, e.getCount());
        ins.executeInsert();
    }
    i = rcvd.entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        e = i.next();
        ins.bindString(1, e.getElement());
        ins.bindLong(2, 0);
        ins.bindLong(3, e.getCount());
        ins.executeInsert();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    c1 = db.rawQuery("select WORD, CNT from WORDS where SENT=0 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10", null);
    c2 = db.rawQuery("select WORD, CNT from WORDS where SENT=1 group by WORD order by CNT desc limit 10", null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some ideas.

Maybe you could use [batching](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jdbc+batch)?

You may be also able to save some time by iterating over `sent.entrySet()` instead of looking up the count separately.

Split on `[^a-zA-Z]` as you later throw non-letter away anyway.

Can't you use JDK5 loops like

```
for (String in : send) {...}
```

? I guess, `clearBindings` is unnecessary as you always overwrite everything.

Make all fields private. Always (unless you have a very good reason not to). AT least I hope that `pat_rep` etc. are fields.

*Split your method. Shorter methods are easier to read and to optimize.*

Comment: entrySet, JDK5 loops, no clearBindings(), some field changes - got me another improvement by 0.89 (~2s for the sample case)! code is updated. Is batching possible for SQLite? And would it replace the usage of a transaction? I can´t quite combine these Methods.

Comment: @MazePutze I don't know much about batching. I've never used SQLLite, just [UTFG](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=batching+possible+for+SQLite). I'd bet it's no replacement for transactions. *I can't see why you couldn't do both.*

Comment: @MazePutze Btw., there's a poor man's batching, too, assuming, the DB supports it: `insert into WORDS values (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)` or even more tuples at once. It makes the code rather ugly. *But before doing anything, I'd measure, what code part takes the longest.*